# How to reverse the lines between a pattern into another file

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I have the following in the input file

```
#Start para
0 hello dq
1 world dq
2 welcomes dq
3 you dq
#Start para
0 how tq
1 are tq
2 you tq
#Start para
0 say dq
1 hello dq
2 to dq
3 the dq
4 world dq
```

I want this directed to another file like this

```
#Start para
3 you dq
2 welcomes dq
1 world dq
0 hello dq
#Start para
2 you tq
1 are tq
0 how tq
#Start para
4 world dq
3 the dq
2 to dq
1 hello dq
0 say dq
```

How can I do this using `sed` or `awk`? Basically I want the paragraph within the `#Start para` reversed. But the order of the paragraphs should remain the same.

Comment: The last five lines are reversed, but the are not between a pattern. You description doesn't match your question. What is the real problem? Why does this have to be done with `sed`/`awk`?

Answer (score 5):

If the only `#` are the beginning of the block then with `awk` you can try

```
$ awk -F'\n' 'BEGIN{RS="#"}NR>1{print "#"$1;for(i=NF-1;i>1;i--)print $i}' file
```

Result:

```
#Start para
3 you dq
2 welcomes dq
1 world dq
0 hello dq
#Start para
2 you tq
1 are tq
0 how tq
#Start para
4 world dq
3 the dq
2 to dq
1 hello dq
0 say dq
```

Comment: This worked. If I have to replace the above "#Start para" with a sequential numbering like #Start para 1....#Start para 2...#Start para 3 and so on , how can I do it. I want this done and replaced within the same and not output it to another file.

Comment: This worked. If I have to replace the above "#Start para" with a sequential numbering like #Start para 1....#Start para 2...#Start para 3 and so on , how can I do it. I want this done and replaced within the same and not output it to another file.

Comment: @vini If you are using recent GNU `awk` you can add `-i` option to edit the file in place. Concerning sequential paragraphs it is unclear to me what you are asking, perhaps it is better to ask new question and describe the problem precisely.

Answer (score 3):

With `sed`:

```
sed '/#Start para/{x;G;s/^\n//;p;s/.*//;x;d};G;s/\n$//;h;$!d' input.file
```

For lines which consist `#Start para` append it to the end of `hold space` by e`x`change: *pattern space* <-> *hold space* then return data from *hold* appendin`G` it to *pattern*. (same can be done by `H`(append to hold) then return to pattern by `g`). If hold space was empty, pattern space will start with empty line so it removed by `s/^\n//` and `p`rint collected lines. Next commands (till `}`) aim to clean hold and pattern spaces and go to next line.

For other lines (which do not consist `#Start para`) appengin`G` hold space to pattern, remove empty line (if hold space was empty), then put pattern space into hold and start new loop `d`elete everything if it is not last line. If it the last line print formed pattern space as default.

Answer (score 2):

For a more conservative, less cryptic approach...

```
awk '
  /^#/ { printf "%s",out ; print ; out = "" }
  /^[0-9]/ { out = $0 RS out }
  END { printf "%s",out }
'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `tac`. Yes there is a command called `tac` which does reverse of `cat`

Comment: `tac` is cool, but in this example all blocks would be reversed, what is not expected result by OP.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a three-pronged approach:

```
sed 's/^#/\n#/' file | 
    perl -00lne '@A=split(/\n/); print shift(@A); print join "\n", reverse @A' | 
        grep .
```

#### Explanation

- The `sed` command adds a newline before each line that starts with a `#`. This enables us to use Perl's paragraph mode (see below).
- The Perl options:

  - `-00` activates "paragraph mode" a "line" is defined by 2 `\n` characters.
  - `-l` : removes trailing newlines and adds a  `\n` to each `print` call.
  - `-n` : read an input file line by line (or paragraph by paragraph in this case).
  - `-e` : the script that will be run on each line.
- The Perl script:

  - `@A=split(/\n/);` : split this line (paragraph) into the array `@A`, making each individual line (real line here, not paragraph) into an element of the array.
  - `print shift(@A);` : remove the 1st element of `@A` (the header line) and print it.
  - `print join "\n", reverse @A'` : reverse the remaining elements of `@A`, connect them with `\n` characters and print.
- `grep .` : just a dirty hack to remove the blank lines added by `sed`. This will print all lines that contain at least one character.